# How to run the delete command via Process?

Tags: c#, class, process, class-library

This does not work, it cant find del.exe...

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "del.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "*.bak";
        p.Start();
        p.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. You should be using the [`File.Delete` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) instead.

Sample code:

```
string sourceDir = @"C:\Backups";   // change this to the location of the files
string[] bakList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.bak");

try
{
    foreach (string f in bakList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
}
catch (IOException ioex)
{
    // failed to delete because the file is in use
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaex)
{
    // failed to delete because file is read-only,
    // or user doesn't have permission
}
```

Comment: how do I make it ignore the error when , the deletion fails ?

Comment: @001: Using a [`try`-`catch` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx). I've updated my answer with an example that catches the two exceptions you're most likely to encounter (they're listed on the documentation page I linked to in my answer). You can either *do* something in the `catch` block, or leave it empty as shown, which will simply ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

If there a reason you're choosing to execute Process over [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) coupled with [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)?